# Logout of Facebook in app using Facebook ios SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, xcode4.5

I have integrated Facebook login in my app and therfore user can login with both my app account and also Facebook and do corresponding actions.For Facebook integration I have added Facebook SDK.Now when Logout button is clicked in my app it has to clear all the credentials of Facebook Account.I have gone for :

```
-(IBAction)btnlogOutClicked:(id)sender
{
  [appDelegate fbDidlogout]; 
}
-(void)fbDidlogout
{
    FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
    [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [session close];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];


}
```

But when I again click on button I m redirected directly to my  account without going to Facebook Login page.

How can I logout of Facebook?

Comment: Which SDK? There are many. (PHP, Js, C#)...

Comment: Facebook ios SDK is the one I m using...

Comment: This code is working fine for me :)

Answer (score 85):

Using new Facebook SDK login kit just write below line and thats it..

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

---

If using swift, make sure to have the necessary imports

```
import FBSDKLoginKit

func logout() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
}
```

Comment: Is this working? `FBSDKLoginManager` need to be same as used in login? or may be new object.?

Comment: Working so smooth! Thx

Comment: on later revisions, the class has ben renamed to `LoginManager()` only

Answer (score 20):

For logout you should try this

you can **add the Logout button on Navigation Controller** (Top Right Corner) in **viewDidLoad** method

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(logoutButtonWasPressed:)];
```

and the **action method for above added button** is

```
-(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Hope this will help you!

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/)

**Edit:**

As you asked why its not asking for UserName and Password,So the reason is :

When we integrate Facebook SDK in our app and try to login, it automatically check two places (to make sure we have already logged-in Facebook or not)

1. First of all It checks whether we have already logged-in into Facebook Native app which is installed on this device.
2. then It checks whether we have saved our FaceBook UserName and Password in Device Settings.

If both places we haven't logged-in then It will ask UserName and Password in application

you can check Facebook account setup in Device Settings as shown in below screen shot,

Press Home Button --> Settings -->Facebook

[image]

Comment: I tried with ur code but it get login with my credentials if I click on Login buton without asking for login id and psswrd...What else should I need to do ?

Comment: see in iOS 6 we have native framework for Facebook, so when you login from app it checks whether you have already saved login info in Device settings or not, so make sure as like Twitter you have entered Facebook account info in settings, else it will prompt you for UN and Pass whenever you try to login from your app.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u...Now I can Logout of facebook when I open facebook url in browser and then logout there.,Then its prompting for Facebook credentials (Id and psswrd) when I click on Login btn in my app

Comment: @Aaradhya  Plz check added screen shot for Facebook setup, let me know if you have still trouble with it, drop you small sample code to achieve this.

Answer (score 9):

FBSDK is doing logout like this:

```
  [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login logOut];
```

Answer (score 4):

If using swift 3 or 4:

```
var loginManager = LoginManager()
```

Paste this code when some action is need to be done for logging out

```
loginManager.logOut()
```

Comment: @SaschaM78 that for help mate

Answer (score 0):

In your `postButtonClicked` write following if else :

```
-(void)postButtonClicked
{

    _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];
    [_session resume];

    posting = YES;
    showSlideShow = 1;

    if (_facebookName != nil)
    {
        [self logoutButtonClicked];
    }
    if (![_session isConnected])
    {
        self.loginDialog = nil;
        _loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];
        [_loginDialog show];
    }
    else {
        self.loginDialog = nil;
        _loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];
        [_loginDialog show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Im using Facebook ios SDK.I have not used any FBLoginDialog.Can u please tell me how can I logout using Facebook ios SDK?