# Implement Facebook Logout using facebook SDK for ios 6

Tags: iphone

How can I implement facebook logout flow,  so that when user clicks on logout button in app, then facebook ask for fresh login. I am using facebook SDK for ios 6.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610152/logout-of-facebook-in-app-using-facebook-ios-sdk  get idea from here

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
-(IBAction)logoutButtonPress:(id)sender {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Comment: it should work, check this  [https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample]