# Why facebook sdk automatically login me into facebook app installed on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'v integrated Facebook SDK for iOS and it is working fine.except this scenario - 
**User not set his credentials in setting, and has not logged in into facebook app**.In this case when user login into my app using `facebook sdk`, the sdk automatically login him in `facebook app` installed on his iPhone?
Is there any way to prevent `facebook sdk` to login user to `facebook app`?I'v searched for the same but unable to find any clue.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has his credentials set up in the Settings.app for Facebook, then the SDK would only ask for permission to use the app without requiring him to log in.

Comment: from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610152/logout-of-facebook-in-app-using-facebook-ios-sdk) it seems that you are not correct, and i'm asking that why user logged in into Facebook app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but can you be clearer on your original question? I'm interested in which method are you using to ask for permissions? Using the native dialogs in iOS 6 and later or through the Facebook app/website?

Comment: I'v no problem with login dialog(permissions), but my question is that why user logged in into facebook app installed on his iPhone by using my app?please check my post again.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: the original question is quite clear!