# FBSDKLoginManager not open login Dialog in native ios apps

Tags: ios, facebook

I am new to iPhone development ,i want to do a facebook login from my native iOS simple application using latest facebook sdk 4. something ,i just want to open a facebook login dialog from Custom `UIButton` click,in my apps and for that i do below code in my button click method..

```
- (IBAction)didTapLoginFaceBook:(id)sender {

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error

        NSLog(@"Unexpected login error: %@", error);
        NSString *alertMessage = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey] ?: @"There was a problem logging in. Please try again later.";
        NSString *alertTitle = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedTitleKey] ?: @"Oops";
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                        message:alertMessage
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];


        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                // Do work
            }
        }
    }];


}
```

This code is work something different,but i want to open a login dialog form Custom `UIButton` Click in the native iOS apps.

So,please suggest the right way with some code,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Facebook login 4.x with custom button in Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut];
             }
         }
     }];
}

- (void)fetchUserInfo {
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location , friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);

             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

**Facebook login 4.x with custom button in Swift**

```
@IBAction func btnFacebookPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.browser;

    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self, handler: {(result : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error : Error?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // Process error
        }
        else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {
            print("result is: \(result)");
            self.fetchUserInfo()
            loginManager.logOut()
        }
    })
}


func fetchUserInfo() {
    if let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()?.tokenString {
        print("Token is available : \(accessToken)")

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location , friends ,hometown , friendlists"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result : Any?, error : Error?) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
            else if let result  = result {
                print("result:\(result)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: and how it logout the current user? when i again pressed login button then it directly go the " you Already authorized demo apps " ..

Comment: i use another button for logout ,

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya yes, add this code in your logout button's action

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya `[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];`

Comment: Remove the code of logout from the login button's code and logout your self by button click. you can check this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610152/logout-of-facebook-in-app-using-facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: it's work for me And userdata also get properlly ,but when i login again it;s not ask login credential again directlly goes to safari and prompt of "You have already authorized demo apps"..How can i resolve this issue,please suggest me  ASAP.Thanks in advance

Comment: i use  below  code in logut button pressed                                                    - (IBAction)didTapLogOut:(id)sender {
    
    [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
}

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya brother It will not logout from the safari. you have to manually logout from the safari.

Comment: hello ashish i can't open in simulator

Comment: please help to find solution

Comment: i have upload image please find attach, FB login page not open, loading can't finished

Comment: yes i upload it but it's not approve so you can't see it.

Comment: @AshishKakkad i can't open facebook in safari on simulator also

Comment: @AshishKakkad it's can't load mean click on facebook login from google search it's just loading not open FB. loader stop on middle of the screen.

Comment: @AshishKakkad i have also test on device, Device also can't open FB

Comment: I have share image link please see this https://drive.google.com/a/quickbeyond.com/file/d/0B4gQ07Z3KfdDLXo3dTc0eEtZSEk/view?usp=sharing